# MongoDB UUID Deserialization

Tags: java, json, mongodb, uuid, bson

I have a collection where each document contains a `UUID` stored as `Binary`. I deserialize it using `gson.fromJson(document.toJson(), Class.class);`, but I get an exception of type `JsonSyntaxException` where the `UUID` is being deserialized. Is there a quick fix for this problem or do I have to change the way I store my `UUID` (Would it be efficient to store it as `String`)?

Edit:
I changed the UuidRepresentation to `STANDARD`, and it works serializing it to a type 4, but when Document#toJson is called, it is deserialized back into a type 3.. Is it possible to set the UuidRepresentation for Document#toJson too?

Comment: Are you sure it's an `UUID`? MongoDB by default uses `ObjectId`

Comment: Would  [UuidRepresentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/index.html?org/bson/UuidRepresentation.html) be useful here?

Comment: @Joe I tried changing from JAVA_LEGACY to STANDARD with no luck, and I know it's a UUID, I set it myself.

Comment: I don't think JSON has a UUID representation other than String, does it?

Comment: @Joe You're right, so I would probably want to find a way to convert from binary to string and then string to UUID perhaps